# How to customize "language switcher" button link in wordpress using wpml plugin?

Tags: wordpress, translation, wpml

I am making a custom `auton.php` file in wordpress. In my web i have made profile in of teacher/gurus when i open them it opens right profile but issue is when i switch to any language it always open admin profile in stead of that particular profile

[image: Like shown in this image/screenshot]

Comment: Are you using a default WPML switcher or you created a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please make sure your theme is WPML compatible. Here is  compatible theme [list](https://wpml.org/documentation/theme-compatibility).
- Also make sure you are using updated Plugins and Theme.
- Please make sure minimum [requirements](https://wpml.org/home/minimum-requirements/) for WPML meet.
- Please check for a possible theme and plugin conflict. To do that you can switch back to any default theme (e.g. Twenty Seventeen theme), Disable all plugins except WPML and see if this issue goes away with default theme and only WPML activated?

Comment: i'm making a custom theme, is there any hook or function for that so we can use it according to our needs

Comment: Try to follow this https://wpml.org/documentation/support/achieving-wpml-compatibility-for-your-themes-and-plugins/

Comment: Thank you. Plugin is conflicting with WPML.